legend not showing in ggplotly after using guide
the legend doesn't appear in ggplotly when I use guide in ggplot :
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut,color) %>% 
  summarise(price = mean(price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cut,y=price,fill= color))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')  +  
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) -> t
ggplotly(t) 

If I remove the line with guides, no problem :
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut,color) %>% 
  summarise(price = mean(price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cut,y=price,fill= color))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity') -> t
ggplotly(t) 

How could I use the guide but still keep the legend in ggplotly ?
Edit : As spotted by @Stefan, the problem was that I used plotly 4.10.3, after updating, legend appears normally.

Your code works fine. But I remember that there was an issue with guides() in the past, i.e. check your plotly version. Mine is 4.10.4.

... but note that reverse=TRUE seems to have no effect. So you probably have to that by converting to a factor with reversed levels.
